# Can you remove an event listener added by $.on() from an element bubbling up to the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Given something like this `$('body').on('click', 'a', someReference);` is there any way to remove this listener for a specific `<a>` using `$.off()`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u3tjavrf/8/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ... is there any way to remove this listener for a specific `<a>` using `$.off()`?

No. Simply because there is no handler attached to any of the `<a>`. You are using *event delegation*. The handler is attached to `<body>` and only executed if it originates on a `<a>`.

But you can bind an event handler to the specific `a` that stops the event propagation:

```
$(specific_a).on('click', false);
```

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
     console.log($(this).text());   
});
$('a').eq(1).on('click', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">normal</a>
<a href="#">stopped</a>
```